# System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient does not exist on windowsphone,how to fix this?

Tags: silverlight, sockets, windows-phone-7, tcpclient, modbus

I'm working on a program that connects to different brands of plc's and therefor uses different protocols to communicate with them. I have found a nice little library [(Click for library project page)](http://code.google.com/p/free-dotnet-modbus/) to implement the Modbus Protocol. it worked like a charm when i've tested it (in console). But now i want to implement it on my windowsphone application it comes up with some errors of namespaces not being found.

After some time on google i've found out that the silverlight frame work does not implement the:
System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient Namespace

Therefor i can't use this library.. Is their any "simple" work around to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is socket support in the Mango version of the Windows Phone 7 SDK, `TcpClient` itself still isn't supported. It's entirely possible that the library you want to use would try to use the synchronous APIs anyway - only the asynchronous socket operations are supported in [`System.Net.Sockets.Socket`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket%28v=vs.95%29.aspx).

You should have a look at the library you want to use and see how hard it would be to make it use the asynchronous operations on `Socket` directly - and I'd suggest asking on the modbus mailing list to see if anyone's already done this.

Comment: Oke, thanks for your reply. That kinda sucks, i hoped there was an alternate lib in silverlight that was equivalent. Now, ive got to re-write this library to be able to get it working on different platforms. Bummer :( but thanks for the info ;)